# AllegroGraph Query Plan

Tags: sparql, query-performance, allegrograph

Is it possible to view the query execution plan for evaluating a SPARQL query in AllegroGraph (something like `EXPLAIN`).

Answer (score 0):

AllegroGraph provides a query analyzer through a Lisp API and REST API that will tell you what indices are being utilized. For more information, look at the following link (this is for AllegroGraph v4.14.1):

http://franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/v4/query-analysis.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no `explain` query command in SPARQL, but here are two ways to execute SPARQL queries with verbose output which includes the query plan:

- click "Show Plan" in [AllegroGraph Webview](https://franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/6.7.0/agwebview.html);
- or add the [AllegroGraph query option](https://franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/6.7.0/sparql-reference.html#query-option.logQuery) `PREFIX franzOption_logQuery: <franz:yes>` to the query, which will write an execution log to `agraph.log`